# crash at [NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to remove a file from path using following code. But my application is crashing while removing file from the path.

```
- (void)saveEditedSavedFile:(NSString*)editedfile As:(NSString*)originalFile
{
    [originalFile retain];
    NSArray* dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0]; 

    NSError* error = nil;

    NSString *editedFilePath=[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:editedfile];

    NSFileManager* fileMngr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if([fileMngr fileExistsAtPath:originalFile])
    {
nslog(@"%@", originalFile); // nslog always prints the correct path even if it crashes..
        [fileMngr removeItemAtPath:originalFile error:NULL];
    }

    if ([fileMngr moveItemAtPath:editedFilePath toPath:originalFile error:&error] != YES)
    {
        UIAlertView* alertView1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Unable to Save File. Please Choose a Diffrent name." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView1 show];
        [alertView1 release];

    }

}
```

Here i am trying to replace an already existing file with a new file.(Moving a file operation) but it crashes at [fileMngr removeItemAtPath:originalFile error:NULL];

I am getting a call stack like this ..

```
#0  0x99f1dc5a in __kill ()
#1  0x99f1dc4c in kill$UNIX2003 ()
#2  0x99fb05a5 in raise ()
#3  0x99fc66e4 in abort ()
#4  0x99fb4e78 in szone_error ()
#5  0x99fb4fb3 in free_list_checksum_botch ()
#6  0x99ec7a88 in small_free_list_remove_ptr ()
#7  0x99ec45cc in szone_free_definite_size ()
#8  0x99ec35e8 in free ()
#9  0x99ee8adb in fts_close$INODE64 ()
#10 0x99f31b57 in __removefile_tree_walker ()
#11 0x99f31999 in removefile ()
#12 0x0006ed01 in -[NSFilesystemItemRemoveOperation main] ()
#13 0x0005cbd2 in -[__NSOperationInternal start] ()
#14 0x0006eaa2 in -[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:] ()
```

can anyone let me know why my application is crashing? i checked that that path is coming as correct there.

Comment: What thread is this crash on?  Why are you not giving a `NSError` to the line of code that is crashing?

Comment: i already tried with NSerror as well but it is still crashing on same line.

Comment: Does this crash happen on the simulator or on the device?

Comment: Are you deleting files or directories?

Comment: Are you implementing any of the `NSFileManagerDelgate` methods? If so, please post code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess is that `originalFile` has been over released and at some point during the execution of `-removeItemAtPath:error:` its memory has been reallocated.  Try running it with the zombies profiling tool.

Comment: This is unlikely, as in this case the crash would probably occur in the first line of the method.

Comment: any more help on this issue? i am like stuck here & nowhere to go.

Comment: no this issue is random. every time this issue occurs the console displays message "error for object 0x6010604: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)
No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc"

Comment: @Nikolai: If you look at the stack trace, you'll see that the crash occurs in an NSOperation.  This implies that behind the scenes there is some multithreading going on.  That would explain the randomness of the crash and the program is probably surviving the previous method because the memory has not been reallocated at that point.

Comment: @JeremyP :- i have not used any kind of multithreading in my application. Not a single NSThread is there. Can you please let me know how i can solve this issue.

Comment: @Dinesh:  I know you haven't used multithreading.  The Foundation framework is using it, or at leas it is using NSOperation as can be seen from the stack trace.  As for how to fix it, have you tried the zombies tool yet as I suggested?

Comment: @JeremyP: The problem occurs from within `-[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:]`. There are no threading issues here, as everything happens in place, on the current thread. The problem seems to happen in `__removefile_tree_walker` where a bad fts seems to be closed. `fts` is a BSD facility to walk files in a hierarchy. fts seems to be used by `NSFileManager` to recursively remove directories.

Comment: @Nikolai:  **Look** at the **whole** of the stack trace.  In particular, note the line `[__NSOperationInternal start]`.  The fact that its `main` method runs on the same thread in this case **does not mean there are no other threads**.

Comment: @Dinesh:  The only other possibility is that you have redefined NULL such that `NULL != nil`

Comment: @JeremyP i just checked that NULL is defined as #define NULL ((void *)0) and nil is #define nil NULL so i think both are same. Any more guesses here. I spent more than a week on this issue & still no clude why it is crashing :(

Comment: @JeremyP: Of course there might be a lot of threads around. And how many threads are used to delete the item is an implementation detail of NSFileManager. I'd assume that NSFileManager does not spawn threads to remove the item, but that's just guessing. Nevertheless, the problem at hand is probably not a threading issue, as the crash happens on the thread from where the method was called.

Comment: @JeremyP: seems like i am in deadlock now. i tried try catch as well but no help. i am not making any new threads in my application as well. Any more help or guesses ?

Comment: @Dinesh: A good start would be to answer my questions (in the comments of your post) :)

Comment: hi @NikolaiRuhe the crash is happening on both device & simulator. I am deleting a single file no directory deletion is there. I am not using any NSFileManager delegate now although i tried using 1 but this too doesn't give any good results so removed the code. Please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: @ Nikolai Ruhe: No, the issue is almost certainly because originalFile is over released.  The threading point just explains why the crash is random.  Otherwise it would deterministically crash at that point.

Comment: @JeremyP i already retained the originalFile removing the file. Is it still cause the originalFile to be overreleased. Also i have Printed the Path in NSlog just before [fileMngr removeItemAtPath:originalFile error:NULL];so till point the path was properly valid as it was printed on console. How it is happened that it get overreleased just at crahs point ?

Comment: @Dinesh:  you are retaining it at the beginning of the method.  If it was over released, it would have happened before then.

Comment: @JeremyP sorry for my lack of knowledge. But just curious to know if Nslog can print the path of a overreleased string?i am asking this becuase every time it crashes or not it prints the complete path correctly i have just added the line above where i added the nslog in my code.

Comment: @Dinesh:  Because when an object is deallocated, the actual content of the memory is not changed, so it still looks like a valid object.  However, if the memory block is reused (which might be happening inside `-removeItem:`, one of two things happens, either the pointer is now pointing towards trash which will give you the error you see, or it points to a different but valid object which will most likely eventually result in an unrecognized selector exception.

Comment: @JeremyP so any idea how can i save the originalFile in the following function(if it is crashing due to this) i mean making copy of the original file variable so that if it is being deleted somewhere i can still use it safely.. ?

Comment: thanks to all i got the solution for my problem. The actuial crash was happening somewhere much before my application bt the result was shown on the following aline at random times. Thanks to all fot there time.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace looks like there's an implementation error in `NSFileManager`.

The functions that do the dirty work of deleting (nested) files (`remove file` and `__removefile_tree_walker`) use BSD's "fts" facility (see `man fts`) to walk the directory structure. In the latter function an `FTS` handle gets closed that is not open. This is definitely a bug in the implementation. You should [file a radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

How that can happen is a matter of guessing. I'd look in the direction of concurrent operations on the filesystem (parallel deletion on the same item, moving part of the hierarchy while it gets deleted, ...).

Comment: i am deleting it from a single point and i have not used multithread in my application.